# Still got "OSError: /lib64/libstdc++.so.6: version `GLIBCXX_3.4.26' not found" error even the `GLIBCXX_3.4.26' is existed already

Tags: docker, gcc, git-bash, libstdc++

I am packaging a docker image using Git Bash and at the image testing stage, the code always returned an error of:

```
"OSError: /lib64/libstdc++.so.6: version `GLIBCXX_3.4.26' not found"
```

I have used a command `strings /lib64/libstdc++.so.6 | grep GLIBCXX` to check which GLIBCXX versions that I have. It shows:

```
GLIBCXX_3.4
GLIBCXX_3.4.1
GLIBCXX_3.4.2
GLIBCXX_3.4.3
GLIBCXX_3.4.4
GLIBCXX_3.4.5
GLIBCXX_3.4.6
GLIBCXX_3.4.7
GLIBCXX_3.4.8
GLIBCXX_3.4.9
GLIBCXX_3.4.10
GLIBCXX_3.4.11
GLIBCXX_3.4.12
GLIBCXX_3.4.13
GLIBCXX_3.4.14
GLIBCXX_3.4.15
GLIBCXX_3.4.16
GLIBCXX_3.4.17
GLIBCXX_3.4.18
GLIBCXX_3.4.19
GLIBCXX_3.4.20
GLIBCXX_3.4.21
GLIBCXX_3.4.22
GLIBCXX_3.4.23
GLIBCXX_3.4.24
GLIBCXX_3.4.25
GLIBCXX_3.4.26
GLIBCXX_3.4.27
GLIBCXX_3.4.28
GLIBCXX_3.4.29
GLIBCXX_3.4.30
GLIBCXX_3.4.31
GLIBCXX_3.4.32
GLIBCXX_TUNABLES
GLIBCXX_DEBUG_MESSAGE_LENGTH
```

It shows that I have already have `GLIBCXX_3.4.26` included. However, when testing docker image, it still shows that `` "OSError: /lib64/libstdc++.so.6: version `GLIBCXX_3.4.26' not found" ``. I have restarted Git Bash and Docker, but the error persists.

How can I solve this strange issue? Thanks.

Comment: `packaging` what exactly does it mean? What exact commands are you executing? `docker image` what image exactly?  `using Git Bash` How are you "packing" a  docker image using "git bash"? What platform are you running on? `at the image testing stage` What is a "stage"? Are you testing it, or is this a reference to some Ci/CD tool? `the code` What code exactly? How was it compiled? Where is it from? What is it executing exactly? `I have used a command` Did you execute it inside the docker image you are executing? Which docker image? `when testing docker image` How are you testing it exactly?